# Printf does not stop printing when it reaches a null character

Tags: linux, string, null, printf

Im trying to debug a null dereference in my program. The program receives data from a web form submitted by the user. It seems that the problem is related with empty fields. When user submit the form the table data is finally retrieved in a `char *tabledata` variable.

`tabledata` handle the data of the table using this format:

```
"row1column1value/row1column2value/row1column3value|row2column1value/row2column2value/row2column3value|\0"
```

For debugging purpose im printing `tabledata` content using:

`printf("\n tabledata is = %s \n\n", tabledata);`

But when i submit the table if i leave the first column of the second row empty im getting this output:

```
 tabledata is = 11/22/33/44/55/22/33|(null)/1/44/55/88/33/44|
```

How is it possible that `printf` does not stop printing when it reaches a null character? How can i check that this `(null)` value is really a `\0` null character?

Answer (score 0):

`%s` along with `printf` will not do it.

You have to use `puts(tabledata);`

Hope this answers your question.